# How can i convert an ArrayList to Flux?

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux

I want to convert an `ArrayList<Apple>` to `Flux<Apple>`

Does Java  8 provide an api to do so ?

If not , how can i convert an arraylist to a flux ?

Comment: `Flux<T>` is not a standard Java type - so no, there isn't a built-in API to do that.

Comment: Do you _understand_ the difference between a `Flux<T>` and an `ArrayList<T>`? **They represent different things** (a stream of single items over time, vs. a defined list at-a-point-in-time) - so the two are not really convertible from one to another unless you define the conversion process yourself.

Comment: ok, so how can i convert an arraylist to a flux ?

Comment: I think you're trying to run before you can walk...

Comment: "Deadlines" :) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to convert an `ArrayList<Apple>` to `Flux<Apple>`

To answer the question directly - you can use [`Flux.fromIterable()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-). Each element in the list will be an element in the flux.

...but I'd also advise caution and rethinking your reasons for doing this here. A flux deals with a reactive stream of elements that are processed individually, a collection is a group of elements all contained within memory at once. If you already *have* a collection in memory, then you're not really gaining anything by "pretending" it's a reactive stream. You can view it as the equivalent of `Flux.just()` for collections - often seen in demos, less so in real-world use.

Quick demonstrations aside, about the only valid reason for doing this is if you're using an API that requires a flux of elements, but the only thing you're able to obtain for whatever reason is a list.